# how to convert date format from 2021-03-18 14:34:34' to '2021-03-18 00:00:00 in mysql

Tags: mysql

tring to use date filter for same date the date stored in datebase for column MODIFIED_DATE is '2021-03-18 14:34:34' format
The where clause condition for filter  is "`where (MODIFIED_DATE BETWEEN '2021-03-18 00:00:00' AND '2021-03-18 00:00:00')`" but it is unable to fetch the records
example query:

```
select MODIFIED_DATE
from instance_history  where (MODIFIED_DATE BETWEEN '2021-03-18 00:00:00' AND '2021-03-18 00:00:00') ;
```

it is showing record not found

i have used this method but it does not helped `cast(cast(left(PIH.PROCESS_MODIFIED_DATE, 10) as date) as datetime) as PROCESS_MODIFIED_DATE` but it does not worked

Comment: What data type is MODIFIED_DATE

Comment: Is it a typo error? I think there is no record BETWEEN '2021-03-18 00:00:00' AND '2021-03-18 00:00:00', cuz they are the same

Answer (score 1):

See below sample

```
select current_timestamp, date_format(current_timestamp(), "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00") 'ExpectedDate format';
```

**current_timestamp**    | **ExpectedDate format**

2022-07-29 17:12:19 | 2022-07-29 00:00:00

Replace current_timestamp() with Modified_Date

Answer (score 0):

Do not use BETWEEN. Use 2 separate conditions (`@date` is needed value, for example, `'2021-03-18'`):

```sql
SELECT modified_date
FROM instance_history  
WHERE modified_date >= @date 
  AND modified_date < @date + INTERVAL 1 DAY) ;
```

When date literal is used then the timepart is `'00:00:00'`.